# SQLAlchemy hangs when external db connection fails

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi

In my application, I use an internal db and an external db where I use the external db to load some details from the main/global database.

From time to time when I try to query some data or commit a transaction, I get an error `sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back` which causes whole application to break down and it's not fixed until I restart it. This mostly happen when the external database is being restarted. We lose connection, the transaction gets invalid and it hangs.

In the FastAPI app, I use SQLAlchemy. I set the external DB as follows (with some redundant details omitted):

```py
class _ExternalDB(DBSetup):
  def __init__(self):
    self._database = Database(self.url, ssl=ctx)
    self._engine = create_engine(self.url, echo=True, echo_pool='debug')
    self._session = scoped_session(
      sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=self._engine, class_=SafeSession)
    )
```

where `DBSetup` is a base class which contains url, database and session. I wrote SafeSession class to try and solve the issue I am having:

```py
class SafeSession(Session):
    def commit(self):
        try:
            return super().commit()
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error("Could not commit the SQL operation!", e)
            self.rollback()
            raise e

    def query(self, *entities, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super().query(*entities, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error("Could not complete the transaction!", e)
            self.rollback()
            raise e
```

An example query is as follows:

```py
external_db_setup.session.query(User).get(user_id)
```

My goal was to roll the invalid transaction back whenever it happens, but the application never gets to the except block because I have never seen any logs for "Could not complete the transaction". Am I missing something?

Full error log:

```py
  File "/***/repositories/user.py", line 8, in get_user_by_id
    return external_db_setup.session.query(User).get(user_id)
  File "/***/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 1004, in get
    return self._get_impl(ident, loading.load_on_pk_identity)
  File "/***/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 1119, in _get_impl
    return db_load_fn(self, primary_key_identity)
  File "/***/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 284, in load_on_pk_identity
    return q.one()
  File "/***/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3358, in one
    ret = self.one_or_none()
  File "/***/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3327, in one_or_none
    ret = list(self)
  File "/***/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3403, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "/***/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3428, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
  File "/***/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 984, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/***/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 293, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/***/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1097, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "/***/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1177, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "/***/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1481, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "/***/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/***/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1173, in _execute_context
    conn = self._revalidate_connection()
  File "/***/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 456, in _revalidate_connection
    raise exc.InvalidRequestError(
graphql.error.located_error.GraphQLLocatedError: (sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError) Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back
```

Comment: [This](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/pooling.html#dealing-with-disconnects) is relevant.  A rollback probably won't help much here - Postgres will rollback the transaction if it is being restarted AFAIK.  You may need to trap the `InvalidRequest` exception, close the current session, get a ew session and retry.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is my application does not catch the exception because SQLAlchemy base class already takes care of the exception (logs it). I will add the log to the original question.